# Gitlab metrics report in Merge Requests

Tags: gitlab, bundle, metrics

We are trying to implement differential metrics report in Gitlab https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/metrics_reports.html to display difference in metrics (typically: bundle size) introduced by the MR.

The mechanism is not very clear to us: we know hot to create the metrics.txt for the SOURCE branch, but we don’t understand how to compare it to the metrics.txt of the DESTINATION branch. We have googled the planet without finding much info. Anybody has already implemented this feature?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that the metrics.txt is generated as ARTIFACT during the pipeline execution, and remains there for comparisons against a MR. It's not necessary to commit the metrics.txt in the baseline. The stats.json is generated by webpack-analyze and can be accessed in ${projectPath}/jobs/${args[0]}/artifacts/PROJECT_NAME/packages/${packageName}/build/stats.json`, and from this stats.json we can extract the metrics into ./metrics.txt and store it as artifact.